# Spring Boot Actuator: have a customized status as plain text?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to integrate Spring Boot Actuator with my companies existing infrastructure. To do this I need to be able to customize the status message. For instance if the app is up and running correctly I need to return a 200 and a plain text body of "HAPPY" from the health actuator endpoint.

Is such customization currently possible? Since the Status class is final I can't extend it, but I think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot uses a `HealthAggregator` to aggregate all of the statuses from the individual health indicators into a single health for the entire application. You can plug in a custom aggregator that delegates to Boot's default aggregator, `OrderedHealthAggregator`, and then maps `UP` to `HAPPY`:

```
@Bean
public HealthAggregator healthAggregator() {
    return new HappyHealthAggregator(new OrderedHealthAggregator());
}

static class HappyHealthAggregator implements HealthAggregator {

    private final HealthAggregator delegate;

    HappyHealthAggregator(HealthAggregator delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Health aggregate(Map<String, Health> healths) {
        Health result = this.delegate.aggregate(healths);
        if (result.getStatus() == Status.UP) {
            return new Health.Builder(new Status("HAPPY"), result.getDetails())
                    .build();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

If you want to take complete control over the format of the response, then you'll need to write your own MVC endpoint implementation. You could use the existing `HealthMvcEndpoint`class in Spring Boot as a super class and override its `invoke` method.

Comment: Actually, this does not answer my question.  This still returns a JSON structure.  I just need a plain text string "HAPPY" and nothing else.  Because this aggregate() returns a Health object I don't see a way to do this.  Health and Status are both final so I'm not sure how to customize their behavior.